# Installing Cordova Plugins with Phonegap - no Cordova.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am trying to install a plugin for my application (which is working fine), compiled in XCode using Cordova and the PhoneGap framework.

On the instructions of the plugin I am supposed to add a key to the **Cordova.plist** file but I cannot find it in my hierarchy. [Here is a screenshot of the directories in my XCode project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlZIR.jpg).

What is the fix for this issue?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since PhoneGap upgraded, the **Cordova.plist** file was discontinued and is instead **config.xml**.

[Source](http://forum.wikitude.com/home/-/message_boards/message/193740;jsessionid=6C6CD2B8E437C6BDFA399B0CCDE6F8F1?p_p_auth=E8JvKWjp&_19_threadId=193741)

---

**Edit**: Since the original page has since been deleted, here is a sort-of transcript from the forum thread:

> *Are you using the brand new PhoneGap version 2.3.0, which was release 7/Jan/2013? The Wikitude plugin is currently only tested with PhoneGap 2.2.0. In 2.3.0 cordova.plist has been changed to config.xml*
>
> *From [http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/whats-new-in-cordova-ios-2-3-0/](http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/whats-new-in-cordova-ios-2-3-0/_)*
>
> Cordova.plist is changed to config.xml
>
> The configuration Cordova.plist file has been changed to config.xml – it comes in a new format that is the same as the Android config.xml. If you are upgrading, you will need to convert your existing Cordova.plist by running the bin/cordova_plist_to_config_xml script. The 2.3.0 project itself will warn you (in the console log) if you are still using the old Cordova.plist and tell you to upgrade.
>
> Try to edit the new config.xml accordingly - we are working on a updated Plugin compliant to 2.3.0 in the next weeks.

Comment: THANK YOU! Geez, does Phonegap ever update their docs? They're awful!