# ChildBrowser Plugin Not working on Phonegap 2.9

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, childbrowser

```
I've upgraded the plugin to latest commits from GitHub
Just still not able to include it in the project <br/>
Just two questions <br/>
```

1. How to add it to config.xml correctly (if below is correct)

> ```
> <feature name="ChildBrowser">
> ><param name="ios-package" value="ChildBrowserCommand" />
> </feature>
> ```

1. Any other things I should keep in mind.

Comment: why you should use ChildBrowser plugin ??  is there inAppBrowser avilable on phonegap api

Comment: inAppBrowser doesnot allow you to remian in the app while you try to load the URL . 
Dont be eager to downvote if u canthelp

Comment: sorry i can't downvote you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<feature name="ChildBrowserCommand">
    <param name="ios-package" value="ChildBrowserCommand" />
</feature>
```

Do remember to get the latest plugin code , since phonegap has changed the way parameters are passed to native .m file
For ex :

```
- (void)showWebPage:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
```

and in .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ChildBrowserViewController* childBrowser;

-(void)showWebPage:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
```

Comment: Do you have still the link for the latest plugin? I'm also stuck of this build error for `ChildBrowser` plugin. I followed this link: https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso/blob/master/README-Phonegap.md but it seems not updated. When I try to build in xcode, I got this error: `Property 'supportedOrientations' not found on object of type 'CDVViewController *'`

Comment: Which phonegap version you are using

Comment: I'm using phonegap 2.9. Anyway, I started implementing now using the `InAppBrowser`, hopefully I don't have any issues consuming an OAUTH2 api using this plugin. I am not really sure if `ChildBrowser` is deprecated or it is still effective for accessing protected resource for hybrid apps.

Answer (score 0):

I got ChildBrowser plugin to work with Phonegap 2.9 by following steps according to this thread.
[ios phonegap Child Browser plugin setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303782/ios-phonegap-child-browser-plugin-setup).

PS. Your "feature" setup in the config.xml is correct.